# How to update requirements?

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I would like to know how to update outdated requirements with the multi requirements files setup that cookie cutter uses (base, local, etc...) ?

If i launch a "pip freeze" it will write the requirements in a single file. It will not dispatch them in correct files

Do I miss something ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I fear you have to handle this by hand. When you install a new package, remember to add it to the correct requirements file with the version you want. It's also a bit cleaner because `pip freeze` tends to write sub-dependencies (dependencies of your dependencies).

Comment: Pipenv might help you solve that problem but still need to manually migrate to use it. https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: So the process is:  

- pip list --oudated to see upgrade candidates  

- pip install --upgrade <packages>  

- pip freeze > requirements.txt to freeze  

- split requirements.txt entries by hand in correct files  

- get rid of requirements.txt before commit :)

Comment: This is why I'm not a huge fan of having different `requirements` files, like they do in `cookiecutter-django`. Maybe you can get inspiration from this approach: https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/a-better-pip-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update all outdated python modules with this command:

Linux:

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Windows (Powershell):

```
pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```

After this you have to update your `requirements.txt` with:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you use `Pipenv`:

```
pipenv shell
pipenv update
```

Answer (score 1):

[pip-update-requirements](https://github.com/alanhamlett/pip-update-requirements) updates the packages in a `requirements.txt`-like file (whatever its actual name is):

```py
pip install pur
pur -r requirements/local.txt
```

Pur does not modify your environment or installed packages, it only modifies your `requirements.txt`-like file.

It will also update nested requirements files, unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: I believe this is a good answer, but it would be even better with an explanation.